# Disabled asp button

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

i have asp button like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="ImportToDB" runat="server" OnClick="ImportToDB_Click" />
```

And i need to call a javascript function when mouseover on this button. So i have in page_load():

```
ImportToDB.Attributes.Add("onmouseover","javascript:OnButtonMove(" + ImportToDB.ClientID + ")");
```

javascript function:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function OnButtonMove(id) {
         //something
 }
</script>
```

Everithing work fine **only if button is enabled**. but when i disable button, this javascript function will never fire.

what i am trying to do: I have button and when is something wrong i just disable it. And when user mouseover this(disable) button, I show him DIV with a message.

Can someone tell me why i cannot call this JS function while button is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this button is disabled it can't be accessed from client side javascript only by server side code (post back), a work around to achieve this by client-side way is to use a div control above this button as Graham Clark says like this

```
<div onmouseover="javascript:OnButtonMove(this.children[0].id)">
    <asp:Button ID="ImportToDB" runat="server" Text="test" Enabled="false" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the event is never fired when the button is disabled, you could put the button in a `<div>` and add the event handler to this instead. Then check if the button is disabled inside your javascript function.